# How to determine what the root tag name is for a XML document

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, minidom

I was wonder how I would go about determining what the root tag for an XML document is using `xml.dom.minidom`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
    <child3></child3>
</root>
```

In the example XML above, my root tag could be 3 or 4 different things. All I want to do is pull the tag, and then use that value to get the elements by tag name.

```
def import_from_XML(self, file_name)
    file = open(file_name)
    document = file.read()
    if re.compile('^<\?xml').match(document):
        xml = parseString(document)
        root = ''  # <-- THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK
        elements = xml.getElementsByTagName(root)
```

I tried searching through the documentation for `xml.dom.minidom`, but it is a little hard for me to wrap my head around, and I couldn't find anything that answered this question outright.

I'm using Python 3.6.x, and I would prefer to keep with the standard library if possible.

Comment: I don't think you will have more than one root element in your example above. Only <root> will be your root element.

Comment: @EnkumicahelDereje perhaps I didn't clearly state that part. It just means that the root tag could be `<root>`, <item>, `<arbitrary>`; not that several roots exist in the document.

Comment: I would use `from xml.etree import ElementTree` and get the root element. then process the children. This way you have to read the xml as a string and pass it to the `ElementTree.fromstring(str format of the xml)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the line you commented as `Where I am stuck`, the following should assign the value of the root tag of the XML document to the variable `theNameOfTheRootElement`:

```
theNameOfTheRootElement = xml.documentElement.tagName
```

Comment: The problem is that the tag name might not actually be `<root>`

Comment: Perhaps this is my bad, I don't necessarily want to check if a tag named `<root>` exists, I just want to determine what the root tag name is. For example if the root tag is `<item>` or `<customer>`. I think using `xml.etree` might be my best approach with `xml.getroot()`

Comment: Removed the first snippet to avoid confusion.

Comment: That worked! Sorry I'm new to XML parsing, and Python in general.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did when I last processed xml. I didn't use the approach you used but I hope it will help you.

```
import urllib2
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
req = urllib2.Request(site)
file=None
try:
    file = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    print e.reason

data = file.read()
file.close()

root = ET.fromstring(data)
print("root",  root)

for child in root.findall('parent element'):
    print(child.text, child.attrib)
```